# Why can't clear error message after show - axios - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, use-effect

[First question for context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72929201/react-axios-showing-message-to-user/72929320)

I'm showing using with `localhost:3000/users/:id`
API has 10 user so if request to `localhost:3000/users/11` should show error message

Also want to show message for connection problems too
I've tried to add `setError("");` inside `finally` block but error message stopped working.

If I don't add this time working when I get error but when I fix error error still appear.

I want to show user details again

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function User() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + id)
      .then((res) => setUser(res.data))
      .catch((error) => setError(error.message))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, [id]);
  return (
    <div>
      {error === "Request failed with status code 404" ? (
        <p>{error}</p>
      ) : isLoading ? (
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h3>User Info</h3>
          <p>Name: {user.name}</p>
          <p>Email: {user.email}</p>
          <p>Phone: {user.phone}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default User;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clear your error when the response is OK

```
.then((res) => {
   setUser(res.data);
   setError("")
})
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

---

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function User() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + id)
      .then((res) => {
        setUser(res.data);
        setError("")
      })
      .catch((error) => setError(error.message))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, [id]);
  return (
    <div>
      {error === "Request failed with status code 404" ? (
        <p>{error}</p>
      ) : isLoading ? (
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h3>User Info</h3>
          <p>Name: {user.name}</p>
          <p>Email: {user.email}</p>
          <p>Phone: {user.phone}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default User;
```